# Adding a call linked to a contact with the API

Tags: api, orocrm

I'm trying to figure out how to link a call to a client in ORO CRM 3.1 with the API.  This is what I have right now, which works fine.

```
   "data":{  
      "type":"calls",
      "attributes":{  
         "subject":"Cold Call my phone 2",
         "phoneNumber":"4444444444",
         "callDateTime":"2020-01-01T13:33:49Z",
         "duration":"217"
      },
      "relationships":{  
         "callStatus":{  
            "data":{  
               "type":"callstatuses",
               "id":"completed"
            }
         },
         "direction":{  
            "data":{  
               "type":"calldirections",
               "id":"outgoing"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Anyone knows how to add a client and/or contact in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone seeing this, the answer is

```
"activityTargets": {
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "contacts",
          "id": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
```